# Использование JPanel вместо JMenuItem в JMenu

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать так, чтобы панелька подсвечивалась так же, как и обычная `JMenuItem` при наведении курсора?

Ситуация такова: есть `JMenu`, в котором несколько `JMenuItem` и одна `JPanel` (используемая в качестве пункта меню), при наведении на `JPanel` курсора она не подсвечивается как другие `JMenuItem`.

Comment: поделитесь с нами, зачем вам панель в меню?

Comment: как только найду решение, обязательно поделюсь. это в двух строках не расскажешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

лучший способ действительно не использовать JPanel в JMenu как JMenuItem, а просто добавить нужные элементы прямо в JMenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

1. поставь листенер на JPanel
2. при наведении миши на него меняешь бекграунд

Comment: это первый вариант, который я попробовал, и он работает, но как в таком случае получить цвет стандартной подсветки других JMenuItem, чтобы подсветка была у всех пунктов меню одинаковой?

Comment: первое что пришло в голову, найди где-то значения RGB стандартного цвета и подставлять бэкграунд колор.

Comment: спасибо, попытаюсь найти.

Comment: но хотелось бы попытаться использовать и другие варианты, если таковые имеются.

Comment: угу, есть еще способа - не использовать JPanel в JMenu как JMenuItem

Comment: я бы с радостью не использовал, но так уж сложились обстоятельства, что очень нужно:-)